# Move iPhone Backup Folder to external hard drive, and later back to my laptop?

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup

On my laptop I have a backup of my older iPhone, under `MobileSync/Backup/[some-string]`.

I want to backup my new iPhone device and don't have the space to do so.

I want to move the older backup to an external hard drive, so if for some reason i'll ever need it, I could copy it back to my laptop.

The backup is encrypted. Is it enough to simply cut and past the `some-string` folder and that's it? Or is this going to break anything? for example maybe another file contains some important meta data that will make the backup useless without it?

Comment: Is that folder not already backed up to an external, as part of your laptop's backup?

Comment: No, since I rarely back up my  whole laptop to the external drive. Normally I just add to the existing backup new files that weren't on it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you copy/move the entire "some-string" folder, that will work. That folder altogether as a unit is the entire backup, including the encryption information.